# function tagged `stdcall` isn't recognized as `stdcall`

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build [this sample code](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Simple_Spatial_Experiments) from a vendor in Visual Studio 2013. There is no project file in the sample, just the source.

The code defines a callback function, SpatialDataHandler, which is tagged with the `__stdcall`. The function is passed to the vendor's API function, which requires an `__stdcall` argument. And yet, I get the following error (compiling as C):

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(CPhidgetSpatialHandle,void *,CPhidgetSpatial_SpatialEventDataHandle *,int)' to 'int (__stdcall *)(CPhidgetSpatialHandle,void *,CPhidgetSpatial_SpatialEventDataHandle *,int)'    n:\phidget\spatial-capture\spazcap\spazcap.cpp  60  1   spazcap
```

The tl;dr of that error message is: Can't convert the cdecl function argument to the stdcall function parameter.  (Compiling as C++ yields essentially the same error, but C2664 instead of C2440.) I have checked the docs and the `__stdcall` keyword appears to be in the right place, and generates no error on its own, so WTH?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Right you are; my eyes skipped right over that macro. You shoulda posted that as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__stdcall` is being defined as nothing in the macro

```
#ifndef WIN32 
#define __stdcall
#endif
```

So, VC is falling back to `_cdecl`, which is the default.

Comment: And the reason _stdcall was overridden was, the `#ifdef` was based on `WIN32` instead of `_WIN32`. Maybe that's valid under gcc, which is what Phidget actively supports.